# How to data be stored in Stack and Queue in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack, queue

When i one by one push data in stack and add data in queue then it's stored without sorting but when i am using loop and push these same data in stack and add in queue then data stored as sorted. Another thing is, when i am push data in stack one by one it's store data one by one but for queue it's store data randomly. I can't understand how to be data store in stack and queue ? 
Here the code:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Stack_Queue_RealtionTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        Queue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

        stack.push(5);
        stack.push(2);
        stack.push(3);
        stack.push(1);
        stack.push(4);
        stack.push(6);

        queue.add(5);
        queue.add(2);
        queue.add(3);
        queue.add(1);
        queue.add(4);
        queue.add(6);

        System.out.println("STACK: " + stack + "\nQUEUE: " + queue);
        System.out.println("\nAFTER POP AND POLL\n");
        System.out.println("STACK: " + stack.pop() + "\nQUEUE: " + queue.poll());

        stack.clear();
        queue.clear();

        ///using loop
        int[] x = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 6};

        for (int i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
            stack.push(i);
            queue.add(i);
        }

        System.out.println("\nSTACK: " + stack + "\nQUEUE: " + queue);
        System.out.println("\nAFTER POP AND POLL\n ");
        System.out.println("STACK: " + stack.pop() + "\nQUEUE: " + queue.poll());
    }
}
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
    STACK: [5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 6]
    QUEUE: [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6]

    AFTER POP AND POLL

    STACK: 6
    QUEUE: 1

    STACK: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    QUEUE: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

    AFTER POP AND POLL

    STACK: 6
    QUEUE: 0
```

Comment: That's because you put `i` into the lists, not `x[i]`.

Comment: Oh, and if you iterate over an array with indexes, use `i<length` instead of `<=`. Otherwise, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Maybe using a foreach loop would make this easier.

Comment: Thank you. Using foreach loop it's printed same value.

Comment: But in queue, how data be stored ? @MalteHartwig

Comment: What do you mean? Both stack and list are just lists with some extra methods to access the values in a certain way (FirstInFirstOut for queue, and LastInFirstOut for stack). So they add elements in the order you put them in. Do you want to know about more specific internals? Then you have to read the JavaDoc, I am sure there are more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You used a PriorityQueue in your example. This means that values added to the PriorityQueue are stored in their natural order (or in the order specified by the Comparator - but you didn't use it in this example). To add values to a queue and to use it in the FirstInFirstOut way, I suggest using LinkedList and its methods helping using it as a queue.
2. You didn't write your "for" loop correctly. You should use:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       stack.push(x[i]);
       queue.add(x[i]);
   ```

   }

This means you add the value which is stored at the "i" index in the x array. In your loop you just added value of i, and it was firstly initialized with 0, and then incremented by 1. You should also be aware that in last loop you could get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because in your example length of x array is 6, but the last index of value stored in x array is [5]. For example, if you store only one value in array:  `int[] arr = { 64 }`, arr.length = 1`, but the value is stored at index 0.

Comment: Many Many Thanks. I can understand but i can't understand why 
QUEUE: [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6] 
where my data was x={5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 6} ?

Comment: @MehediHasan You should really just read [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) already. It states " elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time". Use another queue implementation instead of PriorityQueue, and your elements won't be re-ordered. Examples are LinkedList and ArrayDeque.